# Missing space when I change the cell's background color in SlickGrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slickgrid

I was trying to change cell's background color with custom formatter like this:

```
var myCellFormatter = function(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
    if ((row + cell) % 5 == 1) {
        return "<div style='background-color:green'>" + value + "</div>";
    } else {
        return value;
    }
};
```

but this does not color the whole cell.
There is some space between cell's `div` and the `div` in the formatter.

How could I color the whole cell ?

Comment: I found an efficient way to set styles on SlickGrid cells, without using an inner div.  It's not trivial, but it does work well:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/36562844/218294

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a CSS class to that column (`columnDefinition.cssClass="myCell"`) that would set the padding of the cell to 0px.

Comment: Hi Michael, your suggestion didn't work for me, but I solved this by modifying a little the source code :) Thanks anyway !

Comment: Setting columnDefinition.cssClass works, but there seems to be some issue when the value is null (the previous row's style is set). I'll try to debug when I get some time.