# Slickgrid add colour to a cell/ column or row

Tags: c#, slickgrid

I have a slickgrid which works fantastic,  it has calculations/ subtotals / expenses etc, 
The subtotals are not fixed a one row they move down as Items are selected above.

However I am stuck at change the colour of the text in this one cell to red? is it possible? maybe by injecting HTML code in ?
and is there a way to colour a whole column background.. say green? or a row to gray?

Comment: I found an efficient way to set styles on SlickGrid cells, without using an inner div. It's not trivial, but it does work well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36562844/218294

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a CSS class to a column by using the `cssClass` property on the column definition `columnDefinition.cssClass='myCellClass'`

To add a specific CSS class to some of the rows, use the "rowClasses" option specified [here](http://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/commit/26d525a136e74e0fd36f6d45f0d53d1ce2df40ed).

Refer to answers in these two SO questions for detail: [How to add a class to a cell in SlickGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2742166/122005) and [How to change cell's background color in SlickGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2746417/122005)

Comment: Thanks column worked perfectly .. looking into the others now